# Correct way to check against type given by string in Python

Tags: python, json, validation, types

In short, if I have:

```
str_type = "int"
to_check = 1
```

what is the best way to implement the following check?

```
if isinstance(to_check, str_type):
...
```

---

More detailed:

I want to use type information given by one JSON file to check the values of another JSON file.

So if I have `template.json`:

```
{
  "param1": "int",
  "param2": "bool"
}
```

and `with_values.json`:

```
{
  "param1": 2,
  "param2": True
}
```

I then want to do a check like this:

```
if isinstance(with_values["param1"], template["param1"]):
...
```

This code fails because the second parameter of `isinstance()` must by a type object, rather than the string provided.

From my searching, I see some options, such as:

Converting the 'type strings' from `template.json` using a dictionary:

```
TYPES = {
  'int' : int,
  'str' : str,
...
}

if isinstance(with_values["param1"], TYPES[template["param1"]]):
```

or using eval (which is supposed to be discouraged but is safe enough in this case?):

```
if isinstance(with_values["param1"], eval(template["param1"])):
```

or I could just replace the 'type strings' with prototype values:

```
{
  "param1": 0,
  "param2": True
}

if isinstance(with_values["param1"], type(template["param1"]): # or type() is/== type()
```

There is also `pydoc.locate`, but it seems inappropriate to use a documentation module for this purpose. (Also, I can't find a reference for this function, or really any extensive documentation for `pydoc`. Am I missing something?)

Or perhaps there is a better solution available.
So what is the most Pythonic (or just best in accordance with general principles) way of approaching this?
(Let's assume only builtin types, but if the solution changes for self-defined types, then it would be good to include this for completeness.)

Comment: If you're trying to validate JSON, you should be using a library purpose-built for this process, like Pydantic. There's nothing inherently unsafe about `eval()` -- it only becomes unsafe when you pass it untrusted input. If you're in control of the values you pass to `eval()` then there's nothing wrong with using it (other than that there's almost guaranteed to be a better way to do whatever it is you think you need `eval()` for).

Comment: The first one, an explicit mapping, is what I'd go for. You could even automate it a little: `{t.__name__: t for t in (int, str, float)}`

Comment: The most minimal change to your code would be to check against the type's name: `type(with_values["param1"]).__name__ == template["param1"]`, but again, you should be using Pydnantic or something similar, with your models defined in Python.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If you just want to validate JSON, use a purpose-built package. The [`jsonschema`](https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/) package is a nice option and it's simple to use. Defining a schema which merely specifies types should be very simple.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. It seems unnecessarily complex to rely on yet another module to do a simple check like this (don't need to rigorously check the entire JSON structure), but I guess that is Pythonic. Would it be fair to avoid this if I'm trying to minimise dependencies (particularly relevant in commercial setting)?
@MichaelRuth I agree it could be XY, but I will probably want to implement the check without a package and am also curious about the main question anyway, as I couldn't find satisfying answers (though perhaps that is an indication of a bad Y).

Comment: It's unnecessarily complex until it isn't, and in a commercial setting things change, users find new ways to break stuff with bad data. You also need to maintain this code now. If dependency minimization is critical, then sure it seems fair enough.

Comment: My specific scenario doesn't expect very messy or complicated inputs. I'm keeping this option in mind if it starts to look necessary to switch to proper validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution is to build a dictionary with string value corresponding to type. Then we can use build a simple function to check it

```
def check_types(value, expected_type: str):
    types = {
        "int": int,
        "str": str,
        "float": float
    }
    return isinstance(value, types[expected_type])

print(check_types(1, "int"))
```

If you want to specifically check for type and not subclasses(e.g. booleans are represented as integers). Using the following code will return whether the boolean is an integer `False`

```
def check_types(value, expected_type: str):
    types = {
        "bool": bool,
        "int": int,
        "str": str,
        "float": float
    }
    return type(value) == types[expected_type]
```

Comment: Note that you'll get results like `check_types(False, expected_type="int") == True` with this approach. If you want strict type equality checking, you need to use `type(obj) == T`. This is because `isinstance(obj, T)` returns `True` if `obj` is a subclass of `T` which is not always what you want.

Comment: This is an elegant solution for the problem that the user proposes, despite the other comments suggesting a different approach, those don't align directly with the question.

Comment: I'd hardly call this approach to data validation elegant...

Comment: Thanks for input. @ddejohn what would be an elegant solution that doesn't rely on packages? If I want to only validate a few leaves of the JSON, doesn't this solution in a sense implement an extremely lightweight version of what the mentioned packages do?

Comment: @ADuckTyping but this doesn't rely on any packaged lol

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw yes your solution does not, but ddejohn (and Michael Ruth) suggested using a package to solve the base problem of validating JSON (in the direct replies to my question). I prefer your solution because it doesn't add a dependency (though I understand their point in doing proper validation), but perhaps there is a self-implemented version that is a more elegant way to do this particular data validation, which is what I am asking ddejohn to describe.